# (Windows) `dartdoc` generating documentation files for every base library in the Dart's and Flutter's SDKs when running against my (tiny) package

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, documentation, dartdoc

The first problem I encountered — and which I think is related to the main one — is with respect to the `FLUTTER_ROOT` variable.

I don't know why it wasn't preset at some point in the installation, but, anyway, I just can't seem to set it from within VS Code, not even if I open it with administrator permissions.

If I run `dartdoc` in VS Code I get the following error:

```
Documenting <package_name>...

dartdoc failed: Top level package requires Flutter but FLUTTER_ROOT environment variable not set.
```

My configurations:

- My top-level `bin` folder for Flutter is located at `C:\src\flutter\flutter`.
- My `FLUTTER_ROOT` environment variable has the `C:\src\flutter\flutter` value for both my user and the system.

If I run it with permissions in Powershell or Command Prompt, it parses every dart core library (`dart-async`, `dart-collection`, `dart-core`, etc.) and every Flutter core library, which I think is understandable to generate *my library's docs*, but then it also generates docs for all of those dart core libraries. Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: Does using `--link-to-remote` help? Also see http://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24808.

Comment: Specifying only my library with `--include` seems to work, but, some HTML pages get ill formatted.

Comment: Oh, wait, that is working (using `--include`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why this is happening or if it's intended, but one thing that has worked for me is:

```
dartdoc --include <library_name>
```

This will make sure only your package is included in the docs and not its dependencies. From `dartdoc --help`:

> `--include`: Library names to generate docs for.

Just make sure to restart `dhttpd`:

```
dhttpd --path doc/api
```

That all still doesn't explain the trouble I had with the `FLUTTER_ROOT` environment variable (Windows) though.

Comment: As noted in the GitHub issue I referenced above, `FLUTTER_ROOT` is normally set internally by the `flutter` script, so in most cases users aren't expected to set it themselves.

Comment: Did that happen with me because I did 1 extra nesting (accidentally) when storing my Flutter SDK? (`C:\src\flutter\flutter` instead of `C:\src\flutter`)

Comment: Again, as note in the GitHub issue, it's currently expected that you have to set `FLUTTER_ROOT`.  The GitHub issue is about providing a way to avoid that.

Comment: You're right, I was too tired and lacked the attention when I read that Github Issue. I couldn't even note that you're its author.

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble with `FLUTTER_ROOT` environment variable from `dartdoc`, but solved it by setting the environment variable as shown in the image below.

[image: <code>FLUTTER_ROOT</code>]